# android: open alarm or clock app by clicking widget

Tags: android, onclick, android-widget, clock, alarm

Different phones and vendors have different clock apps. code is available that opens the app one some phones. Different answers give different lists and strategies, and they often have problems working.

Answer (score 1):

Reliable way to open clock apps on clicking a widget.

This code describes how the alarm or desk clock app can be opened by clicking the widget. It solves reliability problems with other solutions. It increases power economy by using Shared Preferences.

The code that finds the app for the phone is placed in onEnabled. It finds the app then saves the information in Shared Preferences, to be called by the Update Service. Once the first package is found, it stops searching. If you want to search for both the alarm and desk clock, place the preferred option higher in the array list. It doesnt do this search every time the widget is updated, conserving power. If your widget updates often, this will make a difference to battery life.

If you feel the user may change their alarm app, you could place the onEnabled code in a separate method in the WidgetProvider class. Then call it from onEnabled, and call it when you detect a change in the users clock package.

WIDGET PROVIDER CLASS

> public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
>
> ```
> public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "SharedPrefs";
> private PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
>
> @Override
> public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
>
>     // start UpdateService whenever onUpdate is called
>     Intent sIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
>     sIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
>     context.startService(sIntent);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onEnabled(Context context) {
>     super.onEnabled(context);
>     Log.w(LOG, "WidgetProvider.onEnabled triggered");
>
>     // find the local alarm service
>
>     // this is an incomplete array of alarm+clock services,
>     // in an arbitrary order of priority.
>     // you may need to change the order to suit your requirements
>     String clockImpls[][] = {
>      { "Standard Alarm", "com.android.alarmclock", "com.android.alarmclock.AlarmClock" },
>      { "Sony Alarm", "com.sonyericsson.alarm", "com.sonyericsson.alarm.Alarm" },
>      { "Sony Ericsson Xperia Z", "com.sonyericsson.organizer", "com.sonyericsson.organizer.Organizer_WorldClock" },
>      { "ASUS Alarm Clock", "com.asus.alarmclock", "com.asus.alarmclock.AlarmClock" },
>      { "ASUS Desk Clock", "com.asus.deskclock", "com.asus.deskclock.DeskClock" },
>      { "HTC Alarm ClockDT", "com.htc.android.worldclock", "com.htc.android.worldclock.WorldClockTabControl" },
>      { "Standard Alarm ClockDT", "com.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock" },
>      { "Froyo Nexus Alarm ClockDT", "com.google.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.DeskClock" },
>      { "Moto Blur Alarm ClockDT", "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock", "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.AlarmClock" },
>      { "Samsung Galaxy S", "com.sec.android.app.clockpackage", "com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.ClockPackage" }      
>     };
>
>     PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
>     Intent alarmClockIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
>     boolean foundClockImpl = false;
>     String vendorName = "";
>     String packageName = "";
>     String className = "";
>
>     for(int i=0; i<clockImpls.length; i++) {
>         vendorName = clockImpls[i][0]; // not needed, for debugging only
>         packageName = clockImpls[i][1];
>         className = clockImpls[i][2];
>         try {
>             ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
>             packageManager.getActivityInfo(cn, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
>             alarmClockIntent.setComponent(cn);
>             foundClockImpl = true;
>         } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
>             // Log.w(LOG, "AlarmService couldnt retrieve activity info");
>         }
>         if (foundClockImpl) {
>             // when the first package is found
>             // send alarmCLockIntent to Shared Preferences
>             // and break out of the for loop
>             SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, 0);
>             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
>             editor.putString("VendorName", vendorName); // only needed for debugging
>             editor.putString("PackageName", packageName);
>             editor.putString("ClassName", className);
>             // Commit the edits!
>             editor.commit();
>             break;  // stop searching to avoid setting less suitable options
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

The array of clock apps is not complete, it includes a few common vendors. There will be devices that dont have any of these apps. You can put the apps of other vendors in the comments and i will edit them into the array. I used the app "System Tuner" to find the package info for my device.

The package info has been saved in Shared Preferences when the first widget is placed. Then, the UpdateService calls this information to create the pending intent each time the widget is updated. Recommendation: Update ALL the pending intents and any other remoteviews updates, EVERY TIME you update. This will prevent issues that occur on restart, or changing the orientation, etc.

UPDATE SERVICE CLASS

> public class UpdateService extends Service {
>
> ```
> public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "SharedPrefs";
> private PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
>
> @Override
> public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
>
>     // retrieve data from shared preferences
>     SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, 0);
>     // retrieve all your preferences each time, update everything
>     int background = settings.getInt("Background", R.drawable.bg_box_light);
>     // if cannot retrieve, set default to standard package
>     // if it is not available, widget click will do nothing.
>     String packageName = settings.getString("PackageName", "com.android.alarmclock");
>     String className = settings.getString("ClassName", "com.android.alarmclock.AlarmClock");
>
>     // get appwidgetmanager instance for all widgets
>     AppWidgetManager localAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
>
>     // set up openAlarm PI
>     PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
>     Intent alarmClockIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
>     // construct pending intent from retrieved package info
>     try {
>         ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
>         packageManager.getActivityInfo(cn, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
>         alarmClockIntent.setComponent(cn);
>     } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
>         // Log or debug message
>     }
>     PendingIntent alarmPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, alarmClockIntent, 0);
>
>     // update all widget instances
>     ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getBaseContext(), WidgetProvider.class);
>     int[] allWidgetIds = localAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
>     for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
>         RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout_name);
>         // update EVERYTHING, EVERY TIME.
>         // whatever is not updated may revert to the initial layout settings
>         remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageviewBG, background);
>         remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.analogClock, alarmPI);
>         localAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
>     }
> ```

If you have more than one widget provider, simply duplicate the code starting from `//update all widget instances` for each provider, and change the widget_layout_name. This code updates all the different widget layouts in the same way. If you want to allow different widget layouts to have different preferences, you can change the code to achieve this - create unique identifiers for each widget layout, and have a set of shared preferences for each layout.